# Searching for files in powershell

Tags: powershell

I've scoured all of the internet for this answer. Maybe it's right here, but alas, I'm out of time and we're on a time schedule from the wonderful boys over in legal.

We have some files which need to be retrieved based on particular names which appear in the directory path.

The person who stored and saved all of these files kept the same naming convention throughout. She's pretty awesome and a++ to her.

The file structure is as below:

```
Animals
       -Dogs
            -Folders With Breeds of Dogs
                     -<Breed of Dog>_MA_etc.pdf
       -Cats
            -Folders with Breeds of Cats
                     -<Breed of Cat>_MA_etc.pdf
       -ETC
            -etc
                -etc
```

The person who saved the files was meticulous about file structure and naming convention, so you can expect c:\animals\dogs\GSD\GSD_MA.PDF  or something like that.

While the original author was rather consistent, human error has occured so what I'm trying to do is look for "close enough", basically.

We might have:

- Client Agreements\Netflix\files
- Master Agreements\Netflix,Inc\files
- Rental Agreements\Netflix\files

What I want to do is grab the file structure of all of those and move them to my "E:\sorted" directory maintaining the file structure it has.

So stepping way from animals, we've got a client list from legal with names they're interested. If I look for name:name, i get 27 results. So far not good.

I've tried partial and I get zero results. So here's my terrible code below. Maybe you can make fun of me and show me where I went wrong.

```
$a = Import-CSV C:\scripts\Clients.csv
$a = @($a.Client)
#$a = $a | %{ $_.SubString(0,6) }

$c = Get-ChildItem E:\Legal\ -include ($a) -recurse # | Where-Object {($_ -match $a)}


ForEach($file in $c){
    $dest =  Split-Path -path $file.FullName -Parent | Split-path -NoQualifier
    #Copy-Item -path $file -recurse -Destination "e:\sorted\11\$dest" -force -Verbose
}
```

Comment: 1) What is wrong with the 27 results which you get? 2) Are you saying you want to be able to find, for example, Dogs\Alsatian?

Comment: So stepping away from animals, there's a client list of 1577 names. We have in the target folder a total of 515 folders, 2988 files. What I'm trying to do is get the file, the folder it's in and copy it over.

I guess I'll use netflix as an example.
We have:
`Client Agreements\Netflix\files`


`Master Agreements\Netflix,Inc\files`


`Rental Agreements\Netflix\files`

What I want to do is grab the file structure of all of those and move them to my e:\sorted directory maintaining the file structure it has, which I believe I've done with the Split-Path'ing

Comment: OK, to be absolutely sure, are you saying that "Netflix" is the name, and if it appears anywhere in the path (e.g. abc\def\Netflix\ghi\jkl\files) then you want to copy the whole directory and any files in it to another location? Or does the name have to appear in the last part of the path (e.g. abc\def\Netflix,Inc\files)?

Comment: Yeah, another example of where things aren't really consistent is there's an entry called "Andrew Morton, Inc." but the actual data we have is either a) "Andrew Morton" or b) "Andrew Morton Agreement" .   So while the original author was rather consistent, human error has occured so what I'm trying to do is look for "Close enough", basically.

So I guess what I'm looking for, I need the 4 root directories searched and if a "close enough" result is found, copy it and all files within the folder over in the same structure they were found.

Comment: Are you using Windows PowerShell ISE? If so, using the debugger and examining the values might help you quickly see where it is going wrong: [How to Debug Scripts in Windows PowerShell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Yeah, I"m using the ISE. Technically the syntax is valid so it doesn't report back anything. I'll check out that article anyways, though.

Comment: I added the information from your comments into the question. Please feel free to make further edits or roll back the edit if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that there is a more PowerShell-ish way to do it, but I used a more procedural-type approach.

Using a [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks), I create a set of directories which need to be copied. A HashSet has only one of an entry, so if it contains "C:\A\B", then adding "C:\A\B" again will not add another entry.

The `.contains` method is the .NET one, not the PS one, and similarly for `.replace`.

```
$src = "C:\temp\a"
$dest = "F:\temp\b"

$CsvFile = Join-Path -Path $src -ChildPath "findthese.csv"
$sought = (Import-Csv $CsvFile).Client
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Directory -Recurse

$set = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]

# get the directories with a client name in the path anywhere
foreach($dir in $dirs) {
    foreach($client in $sought) {
        if ($dir.FullName.contains($client)) {
           $temp = $set.Add($dir.FullName)
        }
    }
}

# copy the selected directory structures to the destination
foreach($dir in $set) {
    Copy-Item -path $dir -Destination $dir.replace($src, $dest) -Recurse -WhatIf
}
```

I left the `-WhatIf` in there so you can quickly check it's going to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

If the names in `$a` don't exactly match the names of files, using that as input to the `include` parameter won't help you find just those files you want.

I've got a file named `clients.csv` with the follwong

```
client,gender,fun
fred,m,y
barney,m,y  
wilma,f,y
navneet,n,y
kumar,f,y
konda,m,y
```

In my current directory, I've got a directory named `clients` with the following contents:

```
C:
├───clients
    ├───losers
    │       barney_loser.txt
    │       kumar_loser.txt
    │
    └───winners
            fred_winner.txt
            konda_winner.txt
            wilma_winner.txt
```

**Case-1:**

```
ls .\clients\ -Filter *.txt -Recurse
```

Returns all the text files.

**Case-2:**

```
$people = import-csv -path .\people.csv
$clients = $people.client
ls .\clients\ -Filter *.txt -Recurse -Include $clients
```

Returns me nothing.

**Case-3:**

```
$people = import-csv -path .\people.csv
$clients = $people.client
$clients += 'kumar_loser.txt'
ls .\clients\ -Filter *.txt -Recurse -Include $clients
```

Returns me one record for "kumar_loser.txt".

I'm asserting the pattern in your list (`$a`) don't match the file names.

If I wanted to fix that in my example, I could do something like this...

```
$people = import-csv -path .\people.csv
$clients = $people.client
for($i = 0; $i -lt $clients.length; $i++) {
  $clients[$i] = '*{0}*' -f $clients[$i]
}
ls .\clients\ -Filter *.txt -Recurse -Include $clients
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys.

I took a less scripty approach and procedural approach, as suggested above. Here's the code I used that *mostly* worked, a colleague and I went through and verified the results and some outlier files. I had to double check the errors that popped up and found a few more files that I wanted. Wasn't perfect, but definitely cut down looking through 700 folders and 3000 files. Include is great but filter is what I really wanted. Furthermore, Include doesn't like index values and Filter Especially doesn't, so I had to save it to a variable and filter by that with a * wildcard which *did* work.

Here's what I did:

```
$people = Import-CSV C:\scripts\HelenClients.csv
$clients = $people.Client| %{$_.SubString(0,5)}


for($i=0; $i -lt $clients.Length; $i++){
    $name = $clients[$i]
    Write-Host "Searching for $name"
    $file = Get-ChildItem 'E:\Legal\' -Include "$name*" -recurse
    if($file -ne $null){
        $dest = Split-Path -path $file -Parent
        $dest1 = $dest | Split-Path -NoQualifier
        $from = $dest[0]
        $to = $dest1[0]
        $too = $file.BaseName[0]
        Copy-Item $file -Destination e:\sorted\16\$to\$too\ -force -Verbose
    }
    else{
        Write-Output "No results found"
    }
}
```

I found when you store the results into a variable, if there's more than one, it'll list all of the locations and names, etc. Not pretty. See below:

```
PS C:\Users\me> $ff


    Directory: E:\ParentDir\subfolder\redacted


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                    
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                    
-a----         6/4/2018   1:47 PM          50485 redacted.docx                                                                                                                           
-a----         6/4/2018   1:47 PM         155579 redacted.pdf                                                                                                                            



PS C:\Users\me> $ff.Basename
Redacted Basename 0
Redacted Basename 1

PS C:\Users\me> $ff.BaseName[0]
Redacted Basename 0
```

So I just wanted the first indexed value. I also wanted to maintain the file structure without copying everything over, so I used split-path to kind of take it apart. It's very hodgepodge and not pretty to look at, but it works.